# -webkit-linear-gradient w/ angle reversed in Safari

Tags: css, safari, angle, linear-gradients

On my way to finding a CSS solution to have an evenly colored element with angled beginning to avoid images I stumbled across this simple example: http://dabblet.com/gist/1780333 . This one is working fine, even in IE of the latest, only Safari is reversing it completely, putting it to the end instead of the beginning AND turning the angle partly, at least in my live site it's not consistent. I have, of course, the same values for all browser versions.

Anybody an idea why it is so and what one can do - or an alternative solution without images to come up with an angled left side of an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you found a bug! Or at least Safari is interpreting the angles differently.

This isn't surprising as until pretty recently Safari used the `-webkit-gradient` syntax which is much less flexible. For example, it doesn't allow angles.

Still you can solve your problem by including the old syntax, which still works:

```
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 10% 100%, 0% 0%, color-stop(80%, #000000), color-stop(80%, transparent));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(60% 100%, #000000 80%, transparent 80%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(60% 100%, #000000 80%, transparent 80%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(60% 100%, #000000 80%, transparent 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(60% 100%, #000000 80%, transparent 80%);
```

[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/5277827)

Comment: Hey bookcasey, I think you nailed it - only it's still bringing different results when tinkering with it in Safari vs. Chrome and such (Chrome is already using the -non-vendor-prefix version). Since I wanted to use it with elements that contain variable content (different category names, a nav menu that could be changed) and is not completely flexible in just any browser, too, I will most likely ditch it and will need to come up with a better idea to avoid using an image. Thanks for the help and the explanation!

Comment: Anyone seeking a side-solution: So easy, but I hadn't the idea until I stumbled upon http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/ - working without CSS3 for all kinds of triangles.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a bug - there were quite a few changes between the Working Draft and the Candidate Recommendation for the gradient syntax, one of which is the angle of the gradient:

[image: Gradient degrees syntax change]

From the [IE Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/25/unprefixed-css3-gradients-in-ie10.aspx). Hence the unprefixed version requires a different `deg` value to the prefixed versions. The CR is much more logical (to me at least), with 0deg being a gradient line pointing to the top and increasing in a clockwise direction.

Comment: Interesting to know, it is to hope that they will sync it again anytime.

Comment: Now it's hit CR, I understand that it's not likely to change again.

Comment: Might be worth marking this as the answer for anyone coming across it. The best, most future-proof solution at the moment is to use the prefixes along with the non-prefixed version, and provide differing `deg` values. It's *not* a bug.