# CSS3 Triangle/cut-out Border

Tags: css, border, css-shapes

I'm wondering if there's an "easy" way to do something like below using CSS3, I want to avoid using images and absolute positioning, or similar, and would prefer to use some CSS method to achieve this.

[image]

I would also like to avoid using any fixed heights for this style too, since I'll be using the same style on various elements that all vary in size and colour.

Comment: What have you tried so-far? You'll get a much better response by including some code from an attempt to create this yourself. Here is a good starting point: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: thats a pretty good suggestion as well with the only exception that this breaks if you use percentages or em's in some situations as it relates to varying screen sizes, user agent fonts etc..

Comment: @BrandtSolovij yeah, and after re-reading OP's question, it looks like he may be after a solution that requires more "dynamic" units of measure...

Comment: I have tried the triangles with css :before and :after, however, I was hoping for a dynamic approach with the "cut-out" areas to be transparent. As this style will be used on various different elements and also different backgrounds. I think using different class names with a transparent image for each :before and :after may be my only option :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple clip-path in the CSS:

```
clip-path:polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 95% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 5% 50%);
```

Result (in Chrome):

[image]

<kbd>**[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/k7Rk9/)**</kbd>

But be aware of that the support isn't that great yet for all browsers. Currently it does [not work in FF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) as far as I can tell (I believe you can use SVG for FF instead).

**Update**

Ok, after playing around with SVG (I'm no expert on SVG) I came up with a "prototype" that works in FF:

In HTML:

```
<!-- For firefox -->
<svg class="svg-graphic" width="250" height="36" viewBox="0 0 250 36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <clipPath id="mask">
        <polygon points="0, 0, 250, 0, 235, 18, 248, 35, 1, 35, 15, 18" />
    </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Then set its ID as clipping path in CSS:

```
clip-path:url(#mask);
```

And it will produce this in Firefox:

[image]

(fiddle updated with this code)

Comment: @minitech I don't have IE10 so I cannot test (and no surprise in any case). And I already warned about this in the post.

Answer (score 1):

This allows your cut-out areas to be transparent:

HTML

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

CSS

```
.left {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid red;
    border-bottom: 60px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
}
.center {
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
.right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid red;
    border-bottom: 60px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
}
```

Updated Fiddle w/ background image to show trasparency: http://jsfiddle.net/Eg9jF/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using CSS3 gradients for support in most modern browsers:

[image: banner example]

```
h1 {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  margin: 5em;
  position: relative;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
  content: '';
  width: 2em;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
h1:before {
  left: -2em;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, #ff0000 50%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff0000 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, #ff0000 50%), -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff0000 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, #ff0000 50%), -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff0000 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, #ff0000 50%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff0000 50%, transparent 50%);
}
h1:after {
  right: -2em;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 50%, #ff0000 50%), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #ff0000 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 50%, #ff0000 50%), -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #ff0000 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 50%, #ff0000 50%), -o-linear-gradient(135deg, #ff0000 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 50%, #ff0000 50%), linear-gradient(135deg, #ff0000 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/jJHtl)

(You may run into this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720299/webkit-linear-gradient-w-angle-reversed-in-safari), but you can read how to solve it.)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this for each of the headers in my 3 column row and I only needed a cut out on one side. None of these answers worked for me so I came up with this.

**CSS**

```
#test {
  height: 66px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #2a6999;
  position: relative;
}

#test::before {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #2a6999;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  }

#test::after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33px;
  top: 33px;
  background-color: #2a6999;
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg);
  -o-transform: skew(45deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(45deg);
  transform: skew(45deg);
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kLjt2yh7/2/)