# Triangular border ornament with css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to make some kind of "triangular ornament" bar with html/css. Can you please tell me how to make such?

Here is the image :

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work

Comment: Please show us the code that you have tried so far. This shape is pretty simple to achieve.

Comment: several requirements to get an answer : 1) have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711689/css3-triangle-cut-out-border and many other about this issue. 2) do you have a plain background? 3) what is your code and have tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made this by mixing two triangles and a rectangle see if this is what you want  http://jsfiddle.net/xkwbt73v/5/
HTML

```
<div id="triangle-left"></div>
<div id="triangle-left-down"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

CSS

```
#triangle-left {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 100px solid red;
border-left: 100px solid transparent;

}

#triangle-left-down {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-bottom: 100px solid red;
border-left: 100px solid transparent;

}

#bar{
width:1000px;
height:200px;
background-color:red;
position:absolute;
margin-left:100px;
margin-top:-200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it using one element then have a look at [Pseudo-elements - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

[image]

HTML:

```
   <figure></figure>
```

## [DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/eLouxp9m/1/)  using Background-image

```
figure{
    width:320px;
    height:64px;
    background:blue; 
    position:relative;
    margin:40px auto;
}

figure:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -60px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(32deg, transparent 50%, blue 0%),linear-gradient(147deg, transparent 50%, blue 0%);
}
```

## [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/eLouxp9m/) using 2 elements

CSS:

```
figure{
    width:320px;
    height:64px;
    background:blue; 
    position:relative;
    margin:40px auto;
}

figure:before, figure:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    left: -40px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left: 40px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
}

figure:before{
    top: 0;
    border-top: 32px solid blue;
}

figure:after{
    bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 32px solid blue;

}
```

Comment: Not saying this is wrong, but just one pseudo-element should be enough for this shape (just to reduce a few lines of code :)).

Comment: Not it is not did the OP said he has a white background? because with 2 you can set the body background as you want, give it a try SIR and please let me know.

Comment: Hmm, fair point as long as it is not a solid color background (say an image). If it is a solid color then it can be directly used in the border color.

Comment: Anyhow the OP has choosen i made an update with background-image i hope this will help you all

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5p4yLrz4/ :)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    width:300px;
    background-color:orange;
}
.triangle {
   width:0;
   border-width: 30px;
   border-right:0px;
   border-color: transparent transparent transparent yellow;
   border-style: solid;   
}
```